# What is the fastest way to update a Dataframe when complex conditions exist for both selection and update?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, dataframe

How can I optimize speed for a dataframe update where get and set conditions are complex?

The following method (using `.loc[]`) seems very inefficient:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,0,0,0,1,3,1],
                   'b': [0,2,0,0,4,1,1],
                   'c': [0,0,0,0,1,1,1]})

# GET conditions
np.where(((df['a']==1)&(df['b']==df['a'])))

# SET conditions
np.where(((df['a']==0)&(df['b']>1)))

# Applying GET & SET conditions in update (using .loc[])- 3ms
df.loc[((df['a'] == 0)&(df['b']>1))] = df.loc[((df['a']==1)&(df['b']==df['a']))]
```

Can I lower execution time using df.values & numpy while preserving both of these selection/update conditions?

## Update

Using jpp's answer (importing df.values to numpy and using masks to select/update), the operation ran ~5,500 times faster.

Comment: I believe you need to assign `df.loc[((df['a']==1)&(df['b']==df['a']))].values` (notice the `.values` at the end) for your example to work.

Comment: Running the line:  `df.loc[((df['a'] == 0)&(df['b']>1))] = df.loc[((df['a']==1)&(df['b']==df['a']))].values` produces the output: `ValueError: cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different length than the value`

Comment: OK, with your example data it worked for me. But glad using NumPy fixed your performance issue.

Comment: Ah,the ValueError was only produced when I used `%timeit` on the line including `.values`. Removing it worked fine. Using `time.time()`, the line `df.loc[((df['a'] == 0)&(df['b']>1))] = df.loc[((df['a']==1)&(df['b']==df['a']))].values` seemed to have an identical execution time to the original line in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Pandas is too expensive, consider using NumPy with advanced Boolean indexing.

If you only have numeric series you may be lucky and be able to modify the underlying NumPy array directly. This, however, is not documented or recommended. Essentially, it's advisable to do all your calculations in NumPy and only move to Pandas if/when you have specific tasks suited to Pandas.

```
A = df.values
m1 = (A[:, 0] == 0) & (A[:, 1] > 1)
m2 = (A[:, 0] == 1) & (A[:, 1] == A[:, 0])

A[m1] = A[m2]

print(A)
# array([[0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 4, 1],
#        [3, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1]], dtype=int64)

print(df)
#    a  b  c
# 0  0  0  0
# 1  1  1  1
# 2  0  0  0
# 3  0  0  0
# 4  1  4  1
# 5  3  1  1
# 6  1  1  1
```

Comment: Yes, I do only have a numeric series. This is fantastic. I'll try it out right now.